# .htaccess - directory protection does not work

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I try to protect my dev web project a bit and add directory protection. ("Verzeichnisschutz" in german).

---

This is my `.htaccess` file (*project/.htaccess*)

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the valid auth details"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

---

This is my `.htpasswd` file (*project/.htpasswd*)

```
test:$apr1$3RWv80vU$MJFZn3DHhrB8yPNO6/TDV.
```

---

But I can still enter the website without having to enter any credentials.
I tried different browsers and inspector/private mode.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is your webserver an Apache? If yes, does the configuration allow htaccess files? Check the `AllowOverride` directives in your Apache config. If no, you can't use .htaccess files.

Comment: No I just found out that it is a nginx server. I guess thats why it is not working. `.htaccess` is only for apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nginx you can't use .htaccess files, nginx doesn't have that functionality.

There is an extra page about that topic in [the documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/).

Answer (score 0):

**As** best i know , kindly check the below parameters :

> error_log file in current folder as you stated "/project"

check access_log under `/var/log/` **or** `/var/logs/` directory for future info may help you to understand what is happening actually ...

Double check the permissions user/group to address them into Apache webserver as well .

Finally check httpd.conf :

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

> Find the section that begins with . Change
>   the line from AllowOverride none to AllowOverride AuthConfig

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

**Save** then **close** the file.

```
service httpd restart
```

Hopefully above guidelines help you out with your question .

Have a great day future friend ...

**Mit freundlichen Grüßen**

Comment: This question is not about apache.